# How to use BITS to download from a UNC path?

Tags: vb.net, bit

What is the best way to distribute files to users in remote offices, using [BITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) with a UNC path or BITS with HTTP? I have a VB.NET project which currently downloads from a HTTP path, but there is added complexity involved (e.g. having a web server).

Or is there a better way to do this? Low bandwith usage is more important than speed of synching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider not using BITS at all and use the old favourite **Robocopy**. Robocopy is a standalone command-line executable which is part of [the Windows Server 2003 ResKit tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd) and now standard on Vista/2008. Robocopy has the `/IPG:ms` (Inter-Packet Gap) switch to "dribble" the download, which is designed specifically to not saturate slow links.